# Where to change my WordPress header?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, web

I'm just a WordPress user, actually I've never used WP before until my dad give me his company's website, it has already had everything and I just need to change few things, but I have a problem now that I can't find where to change my header image.

[Here's the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoK9z.jpg)

[And themes customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xycQV.jpg)

I did a lot of research, and I saw that there's an option called "header" in the customize section, but as you can see I can't find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, every theme has its way of displaying option for your header. It may be in customize in

```
Appearance->Customize
```

or may be in theme options. It really depends upon the theme. Every theme can have different style of displaying the option for header but mostly many theme will have it in

```
Appearance->Theme Options
```

Can you tell us which theme you are using so that you can get exact answer you want to know.

Hope you can understand.

Thanks

Comment: Oh God, i see it, it has the Theme's name before "options" and i ignore it!

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much! I don't know what to say!

Comment: Thanks, wondering it worked for you. If you have any queries you can directly message me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check under Appearance -> Header or
Appearance -> Theme Options